# Division by zero Java

Tags: java, language-design, math, language-features

The behavior of Java is explained in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954193/why-does-division-by-zero-with-floating-point-or-double-precision-numbers-not).

But, is Infinity useful for something?

**Float:**

```
public class DivisionByZeroFloat{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(1.0 / 0);
    }
}
```

> Console: Infinity

**Integer**

```
public class DivisionByZeroInteger {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(1 / 0);
    }
}
```

> Console: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
>       at DivisionByZeroInteger.main(DivisionByZeroInteger.java:4)

Comment: [Is asking “why” on language specs still considered as “primary opinion-based” if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/839601)

Comment: In mathematics, this is called a [singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(mathematics)), and Wikipedia directly addresses this specific math problem.

Comment: [§15.17.2 JLS 11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2) states: “if the value of the divisor in an integer division is 0, then an ArithmeticException is thrown. The result of a floating-point division is determined by the rules of IEEE 754 arithmetic”. Note that with [IEEE-754 floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), the float “positive zero” could be a very small value that was _rounded_ to zero. Dividing by a very small value yields a very big value, and the float “positive infinity” represents a number that is larger than any finite floats.

Comment: @gnat my question is over there: Is Infinity useful for something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954193/why-does-division-by-zero-with-floating-point-or-double-precision-numbers-not

Comment: [Yes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1696269/151778). When I'm calculating 5 things 2 of which depend on that calculation the math finds those 2 things to blow up on it's own by sticking infinity in there. I don't have to write code to figure out which ones broke.

Comment: No, Infinity is not useful. Consider: y = (x²-1)/(x-1). What is y when x = 1? Division by zero is undefined and should always throw the exception "division by zero".